# Infinite loop Vs. A loop that overflows?

Tags: loops, iteration, infinite-loop, unsigned, unsigned-integer

I'm learning about signed vs. unsigned types in Java and came across a tricky example question that has me puzzled:

```
Is the following code an infinite loop? Why or why not?

for(long x = 0; x != -1; x++) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!)";
}
```

At first glance it obviously seems infinite, but with long being a *signed* type, am I correct in thinking it will overflow and eventually reach -1? And then the loop will end?

The problem is I can't really test it because it's just way too big.

Comment: "The problem is I can't really test it because it's just way too big." That's kind of the point. There's a whole set of loops that are technically finite, but have so many iterations that they're defactor infinite. This is one of those cases.

Comment: @Alexander Okay so this one technically is finite? This being a question from a lesson that is specifically talking about signed vs. unsigned datatypes and how they overflow when iterating, how would I answer the question? Do you think it's talking about the "technical" finite, or the 'defactor infinite' like you mention? It seems almost like a trick question at this point.

Comment: It definitely seems like a trick question. The correct answer depends on how pedantic they are about truly infinite vs de-facto infinite. At a rate on of iteration per *nanosecond*, this loop will take 292 years to terminate. You can see exactly what happens on overflow by setting the initial value of `x` to say, `Long.MAX_VALUE - 10`